# Reading text file in Matlab results in unknown spaces within characters

Tags: matlab, vbscript, textscan

I am trying to read a text/csv file in Matlab.The file looks like:

```
VolumeDisplacement,9783.47
CenterOfBuoyancy,-0.732585,3.16072e-14,-3.09939
WettedSurfaceArea,2709.66
WaterlineLength,102.156
MaximumWaterlineBeam,20.76
WaterPlaneArea,1774.4
CenterOfFloatation,-6.32016,1.00108e-11,0
```

The file is generated using `vbscript` in `Rhinoceros`. I am using the standard method given in the help file, but encountering a weird problem.

```
filename = 'RhinoResult.txt';
fid = fopen(filename);
line = fgetl(fid);
tline = textscan(line,'%s%d','Delimiter',',');
VolumeDisplacement=tline{2};
```

But, my results are not as expected. The `tline` is storing the strings with a space between each character. Also, there are two unknown characters `(ÿþ)` at the beginning.

```
tline{1} = 'ÿþV o l u m e D i s p l a c e m e n t '
```

The VBScript used to create the textfile looks like this:

```
Sub writeResult(arrResults, filePath, fileName)
    Dim objFSO,objFile

    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(filePath & fileName, _ 
    ForWriting, True)

    objFile.Write "VolumeDisplacement," & arrResults(0)
    objFile.Writeline
    objFile.Write "CenterOfBuoyancy," & arrResults(1)
    objFile.Writeline
    objFile.Write "WettedSurfaceArea," & arrResults(2)
    objFile.Writeline
    objFile.Write "WaterlineLength," & arrResults(3)
    objFile.Writeline
    objFile.Write "MaximumWaterlineBeam," & arrResults(4)
    objFile.Writeline
    objFile.Write "WaterPlaneArea," & arrResults(5)
    objFile.Writeline
    objFile.Write "CenterOfFloatation," & arrResults(6) 
    objFile.Writeline

    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Amitava

Comment: That's probably a problem with the file itself, and not MATLAB.  Did you open up the file and see if there was that character there?  Also, did you try creating a new file independently and seeing if MATLAB gave you the same results?

Comment: Yes. I opened the text file using both Notepad and Notepad++. The file looks alright there. At the same time, I created a text file by typing the letters, and Matlab is reading that file correctly. I want to believe this is the problem with vbscript which is writing the file, but not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), you'll see

> object.CreateTextFile(filename[, overwrite[, unicode]])

Your

```
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(filePath & fileName, _ 
    ForWriting, True)
```

(probably mis-copied from a .OpenTextFile call) fools .CreateTextFile into using Unicode (evidence: BOM, 'spaces').

So use .CreateTextFile correctly to create (and write to) an ANSI file:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(filePath & fileName, True, False)
```